# Search using XPath for huge xml hierarchy

Tags: python, xml, xpath, elementtree

I have huge xml file of 5GB to parse. I am trying to use xpath to print child elements of `<xn:VsDataContainer id="UQ01130U21F2A">` and other elements similar to this `['UQ01130U21F2B',....]`. Tried some online code examples to print out its child elements but failed to see any output.

Here is the portion of xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<bulkCmConfigDataFile xmlns:es="EricssonSpecificAttributes.xsd" xmlns:un="utranNrm.xsd" xmlns:xn="genericNrm.xsd" xmlns:gn="geranNrm.xsd" xmlns="configData.xsd">
    <fileHeader fileFormatVersion="32.615 V4.5" vendorName="Ericsson"/>
    <configData dnPrefix="Undefined">
        <xn:SubNetwork id="ONRM_ROOT_MO">
            <xn:SubNetwork id="ERNC01">
                <xn:MeContext id="ERNC01">
                    <xn:VsDataContainer id="ERNC01">
                        <xn:attributes>
                            <xn:vsDataType>vsDataMeContext</xn:vsDataType>
                            <xn:vsDataFormatVersion>EricssonSpecificAttributes</xn:vsDataFormatVersion>
                            <es:vsDataMeContext>
                                <es:platformType>CPP</es:platformType>
                                <es:MeContextId>ERNC01</es:MeContextId>
                                <es:neType>RNC</es:neType>
                            </es:vsDataMeContext>
                        </xn:attributes>
                    </xn:VsDataContainer>
                    <xn:ManagedElement id="1">
                        <xn:attributes>
                            <xn:userLabel>ERNC01</xn:userLabel>
                        </xn:attributes>
                        <xn:VsDataContainer id="1">
                            <xn:attributes>
                                <xn:vsDataType>vsDataManagedElement</xn:vsDataType>
                                <xn:vsDataFormatVersion>EricssonSpecificAttributes</xn:vsDataFormatVersion>
                                <es:vsDataManagedElement>
                                    <es:healthCheckSchedule>
                                        <es:time>02:00</es:time>
                                        <es:weekday>SUNDAY</es:weekday>
                                    </es:healthCheckSchedule>
                                    <es:platformType/>
                                    <es:mimInfo>
                                        <es:mimName>RNC_NODE_MODEL_V</es:mimName>
                                        <es:mimRelease/>
                                        <es:mimVersion>28.98</es:mimVersion>
                                    </es:mimInfo>
                                    <es:logicalName/>
                                    <es:productNumber/>
                                    <es:applicationConfiguration/>
                                    <es:productName>RNCxxx</es:productName>
                                    <es:site/>
                                    <es:healthCheckResult>
                                        <es:startTime>2020-05-07 02:00</es:startTime>
                                        <es:message/>
                                        <es:healthCheckResultCode>OK</es:healthCheckResultCode>
                                    </es:healthCheckResult>
                                    <es:ManagedElementId>1</es:ManagedElementId>
                                    <es:neType>RNC</es:neType>
                                    <es:productType>Node</es:productType>
                                    <es:productRevision/>
                                </es:vsDataManagedElement>
                            </xn:attributes>
                        </xn:VsDataContainer>
                        <xn:VsDataContainer id="1">
                            <xn:attributes>
                                <xn:vsDataType>vsDataRncFunction</xn:vsDataType>
                                <xn:vsDataFormatVersion>EricssonSpecificAttributes</xn:vsDataFormatVersion>
                                <es:vsDataRncFunction>
                                    <es:amrNbMmMrUlTfcRepeat>OFF</es:amrNbMmMrUlTfcRepeat>
                                    <es:intraNodeIpResourceRef/>
                                    <es:mncLength>2</es:mncLength>
                                    <es:mcAfterPsHoFromLteEnabled>OFF</es:mcAfterPsHoFromLteEnabled>
                                    <es:nbapDscp>40</es:nbapDscp>
                                    <es:mcc>422</es:mcc>
                                    <es:eulFachEnabled>FALSE</es:eulFachEnabled>
                                    <es:mocnExternalNriMatching>FALSE</es:mocnExternalNriMatching>
                                    <es:evolvedHsUePrioLevel>MIMO_64QAM</es:evolvedHsUePrioLevel>
                                    <es:evolvedHsUePrioLevel>NON_HS</es:evolvedHsUePrioLevel>
                                    <es:ecSbhoTimer>6</es:ecSbhoTimer>
                                    <es:iuSccpConRateMeasPeriod>120</es:iuSccpConRateMeasPeriod>
                                    <es:networkResourceIdentifierLengthPs>5</es:networkResourceIdentifierLengthPs>
                                    <es:hsCellChangeAllowed>TRUE</es:hsCellChangeAllowed>
                                    <es:rimOptimizationEnabled>ON</es:rimOptimizationEnabled>
                                    <es:maxAllowedGbrDlPsStream>256</es:maxAllowedGbrDlPsStream>
                                    <es:pcapPositioningMode>SAS_CENTRIC</es:pcapPositioningMode>
                                    <es:RncFunctionId>1</es:RncFunctionId>
                                    <es:cyclicAcb>
                                        <es:acbEnabled>FALSE</es:acbEnabled>
                                        <es:rotationGroupSize>5</es:rotationGroupSize>
                                    </es:cyclicAcb>
                                    <es:hsFachEnabled>FALSE</es:hsFachEnabled>
                                    <es:highPrioScanReserve>0</es:highPrioScanReserve>
                                    <es:offloadDedicPrioEutraTime>5</es:offloadDedicPrioEutraTime>
                                    <es:aliasPlmnIdentities>
                                        <es:mnc>2</es:mnc>
                                        <es:mcc>422</es:mcc>
                                        <es:mncLength>2</es:mncLength>
                                    </es:aliasPlmnIdentities>
                                    <es:ecLocationAttemptUmts>OFF</es:ecLocationAttemptUmts>
                                    <es:gpehDataLevel>ALL_DATA</es:gpehDataLevel>
                                    <es:cbsFirstMsgDelayMargin>0</es:cbsFirstMsgDelayMargin>
                                    <es:loadSharingRrcEnabled>TRUE</es:loadSharingRrcEnabled>
                                    <es:cyclicAcbRotationTime>10</es:cyclicAcbRotationTime>
                                    <es:nwInitCallReestTime>20</es:nwInitCallReestTime>
                                    <es:primaryCnOperatorRef>SubNetwork=ONRM_ROOT_MO,SubNetwork=ERNC01,MeContext=ERNC01,ManagedElement=1,vsDataRncFunction=1,vsDataCnOperator=1</es:primaryCnOperatorRef>
                                    <es:fastDormancyDchPchEnabled>FALSE</es:fastDormancyDchPchEnabled>
                                    <es:mocnDedicPrioEutraEnabled>FALSE</es:mocnDedicPrioEutraEnabled>
                                    <es:initialIuAccessRateMax>0</es:initialIuAccessRateMax>
                                    <es:offloadDedicPrioEutraEnabled>FALSE</es:offloadDedicPrioEutraEnabled>
                                    <es:userLabel>ERNC01</es:userLabel>
                                    <es:rimUtraSiTimeout>40</es:rimUtraSiTimeout>
                                    <es:ecCnSbhoRequestIgnore>FALSE</es:ecCnSbhoRequestIgnore>
                                    <es:ecCnPriorityLevel>7</es:ecCnPriorityLevel>
                                    <es:loadSharingDirRetryEnabled>TRUE</es:loadSharingDirRetryEnabled>
                                    <es:iuSccpConRateThresh>10000</es:iuSccpConRateThresh>
                                    <es:eulUsersAdmEulHsCcEnabled>FALSE</es:eulUsersAdmEulHsCcEnabled>
                                    <es:evolvedHsUePrioEnabled>FALSE</es:evolvedHsUePrioEnabled>
                                    <es:rncType>RNC_8200</es:rncType>
                                    <es:cyclicAcbPs>
                                        <es:acbEnabled>FALSE</es:acbEnabled>
                                        <es:rotationGroupSize>5</es:rotationGroupSize>
                                    </es:cyclicAcbPs>
                                    <es:csPriorityRabSetupTime>100</es:csPriorityRabSetupTime>
                                    <es:fastDormancyMethod>RELEASE</es:fastDormancyMethod>
                                    <es:robustRwrEutraEnabled>TRUE</es:robustRwrEutraEnabled>
                                    <es:gpehFileSize>90000</es:gpehFileSize>
                                    <es:spareC>0</es:spareC>
                                    <es:spareC>0</es:spareC>
                                    <es:fbrPreventAccessEnabled>TRUE</es:fbrPreventAccessEnabled>
                                    <es:nbapAuditInterval>0</es:nbapAuditInterval>
                                    <es:rncId>115</es:rncId>
                                    <es:ctchAdmCtrl>FALSE</es:ctchAdmCtrl>
                                    <es:hsToDchTrigger>
                                        <es:servHsChangeIntraRnc>ON</es:servHsChangeIntraRnc>
                                        <es:changeOfBestCellIntraRnc>ON</es:changeOfBestCellIntraRnc>
                                        <es:changeOfBestCellInterRnc>ON</es:changeOfBestCellInterRnc>
                                        <es:servHsChangeInterRnc>ON</es:servHsChangeInterRnc>
                                        <es:poorQualityDetected>OFF</es:poorQualityDetected>
                                    </es:hsToDchTrigger>
                                    <es:hsOnlyBestCell>FALSE</es:hsOnlyBestCell>
                                    <es:spareB>0</es:spareB>
                                    <es:spareB>1</es:spareB>
                                    <es:spareA>0</es:spareA>
                                    <es:spare>0</es:spare>
                                    <es:mnc>2</es:mnc>
                                    <es:rimUtraSiRetries>5</es:rimUtraSiRetries>
                                    <es:uetrFileSize>275</es:uetrFileSize>
                                    <es:networkResourceIdentifierLengthCs>0</es:networkResourceIdentifierLengthCs>
                                    <es:ctrFileSize>5000</es:ctrFileSize>
                                    <es:cyclicAcbCs>
                                        <es:acbEnabled>FALSE</es:acbEnabled>
                                        <es:rotationGroupSize>5</es:rotationGroupSize>
                                    </es:cyclicAcbCs>
                                    <es:emergencyCallRedirect>OFF</es:emergencyCallRedirect>
                                    <es:evolvedHsUePrioLoadThresh>50</es:evolvedHsUePrioLoadThresh>
                                    <es:softCongestionAllModules>0</es:softCongestionAllModules>
                                    <es:garbledSpeechCorrectionEnabled>TRUE</es:garbledSpeechCorrectionEnabled>
                                    <es:mocnDedicatedCellsSupport>OFF</es:mocnDedicatedCellsSupport>
                                    <es:enhUeDrxEnabled>FALSE</es:enhUeDrxEnabled>
                                </es:vsDataRncFunction>
                            </xn:attributes>
                            <xn:VsDataContainer id="UX01170U9F1C">
                                <xn:attributes>
                                    <xn:vsDataType>vsDataUtranCell</xn:vsDataType>
                                    <xn:vsDataFormatVersion>EricssonSpecificAttributes</xn:vsDataFormatVersion>
                                    <es:vsDataUtranCell>
                                        <es:sib1PlmnScopeValueTag>1</es:sib1PlmnScopeValueTag>
                                        <es:secondarySchPower>-35</es:secondarySchPower>
                                        <es:primaryCpichPower>330</es:primaryCpichPower>
                                        <es:servDiffRrcAdmHighPrioProfile>SPEECH_ONLY</es:servDiffRrcAdmHighPrioProfile>
                                    </es:vsDataUtranCell>
                                </xn:attributes>
                                <xn:VsDataContainer id="41173">
                                    <xn:attributes>
                                        <xn:vsDataType>vsDataGsmRelation</xn:vsDataType>
                                        <xn:vsDataFormatVersion>EricssonSpecificAttributes</xn:vsDataFormatVersion>
                                        <es:vsDataGsmRelation>
                                            <es:mobilityRelationType>HO_AND_CELL_RESEL</es:mobilityRelationType>
                                            <es:externalGsmCellRef>SubNetwork=ONRM_ROOT_MO,SubNetwork=ERNC01,MeContext=ERNC01,ManagedElement=1,vsDataRncFunction=1,vsDataExternalGsmNetwork=422_2,vsDataExternalGsmCell=41173</es:externalGsmCellRef>
                                        </es:vsDataGsmRelation>
                                    </xn:attributes>
                                </xn:VsDataContainer>
                                <xn:VsDataContainer id="UX01170U9F1A">
                                    <xn:attributes>
                                        <xn:vsDataType>vsDataUtranRelation</xn:vsDataType>
                                        <xn:vsDataFormatVersion>EricssonSpecificAttributes</xn:vsDataFormatVersion>
                                        <es:vsDataUtranRelation>
                                            <es:UtranRelationId>UX01170U9F1A</es:UtranRelationId>
                                            <es:creationTime>2023-04-12 11:21:25</es:creationTime>
                                            <es:createdBy>Operator</es:createdBy>
                                            <es:mobilityRelationType>HO_AND_CELL_RESEL</es:mobilityRelationType>
                                        </es:vsDataUtranRelation>
                                    </xn:attributes>
                                </xn:VsDataContainer>
                            </xn:VsDataContainer>
                            <xn:VsDataContainer id="UX01170U9F1B">
                                <xn:attributes>
                                    <xn:vsDataType>vsDataUtranCell</xn:vsDataType>
                                    <xn:vsDataFormatVersion>EricssonSpecificAttributes</xn:vsDataFormatVersion>
                                    <es:vsDataUtranCell>
                                        <es:sib1PlmnScopeValueTag>1</es:sib1PlmnScopeValueTag>
                                        <es:secondarySchPower>-35</es:secondarySchPower>
                                        <es:primaryCpichPower>330</es:primaryCpichPower>
                                        <es:servDiffRrcAdmHighPrioProfile>SPEECH_ONLY</es:servDiffRrcAdmHighPrioProfile>
                                        <es:hcsUsage>
                                            <es:connectedMode>FALSE</es:connectedMode>
                                            <es:idleMode>FALSE</es:idleMode>
                                        </es:hcsUsage>
                                        <es:accessClassesBarredCs>FALSE</es:accessClassesBarredCs>
                                    </es:vsDataUtranCell>
                                </xn:attributes>
                                <xn:VsDataContainer id="41173">
                                    <xn:attributes>
                                        <xn:vsDataType>vsDataGsmRelation</xn:vsDataType>
                                        <xn:vsDataFormatVersion>EricssonSpecificAttributes</xn:vsDataFormatVersion>
                                        <es:vsDataGsmRelation>
                                            <es:mobilityRelationType>HO_AND_CELL_RESEL</es:mobilityRelationType>
                                        </es:vsDataGsmRelation>
                                    </xn:attributes>
                                </xn:VsDataContainer>
                                <xn:VsDataContainer id="UX01170U9F1A">
                                    <xn:attributes>
                                        <xn:vsDataType>vsDataUtranRelation</xn:vsDataType>
                                        <xn:vsDataFormatVersion>EricssonSpecificAttributes</xn:vsDataFormatVersion>
                                        <es:vsDataUtranRelation>
                                            <es:UtranRelationId>UX01170U9F1A</es:UtranRelationId>
                                            <es:creationTime>2023-04-12 11:21:22</es:creationTime>
                                            <es:createdBy>Operator</es:createdBy>
                                        </es:vsDataUtranRelation>
                                    </xn:attributes>
                                </xn:VsDataContainer>
                            </xn:VsDataContainer>
                        </xn:VsDataContainer>
                    </xn:ManagedElement>
                </xn:MeContext>
            </xn:SubNetwork>
            <xn:SubNetwork id="ERNC02">
                <xn:MeContext id="ERNC02">
                    <xn:VsDataContainer id="ERNC02">
                        <xn:attributes>
                            <xn:vsDataType>vsDataMeContext</xn:vsDataType>
                            <xn:vsDataFormatVersion>EricssonSpecificAttributes</xn:vsDataFormatVersion>
                            <es:vsDataMeContext>
                                <es:platformType>CPP</es:platformType>
                                <es:MeContextId>ERNC02</es:MeContextId>
                                <es:neType>RNC</es:neType>
                            </es:vsDataMeContext>
                        </xn:attributes>
                    </xn:VsDataContainer>
                    <xn:ManagedElement id="1">
                        <xn:attributes>
                            <xn:userLabel>ERNC02</xn:userLabel>
                        </xn:attributes>
                        <xn:VsDataContainer id="1">
                            <xn:attributes>
                                <xn:vsDataType>vsDataManagedElement</xn:vsDataType>
                                <xn:vsDataFormatVersion>EricssonSpecificAttributes</xn:vsDataFormatVersion>
                                <es:vsDataManagedElement>
                                    <es:healthCheckSchedule>
                                        <es:weekday>MONDAY</es:weekday>
                                        <es:time>02:30</es:time>
                                    </es:healthCheckSchedule>
                                    <es:platformType/>
                                    <es:mimInfo>
                                        <es:mimVersion>28.98</es:mimVersion>
                                        <es:mimName>RNC_NODE_MODEL_V</es:mimName>
                                        <es:mimRelease/>
                                    </es:mimInfo>
                                    <es:logicalName/>
                                    <es:productNumber/>
                                    <es:applicationConfiguration/>
                                    <es:productName>RNC8200</es:productName>
                                    <es:site/>
                                    <es:healthCheckResult>
                                        <es:healthCheckResultCode>OK</es:healthCheckResultCode>
                                        <es:message/>
                                        <es:startTime>2023-05-01 02:30</es:startTime>
                                    </es:healthCheckResult>
                                    <es:ManagedElementId>1</es:ManagedElementId>
                                    <es:neType>RNC</es:neType>
                                    <es:productRevision/>
                                    <es:productType>Node</es:productType>
                                </es:vsDataManagedElement>
                            </xn:attributes>
                        </xn:VsDataContainer>
                        <xn:VsDataContainer id="1">
                            <xn:attributes>
                                <xn:vsDataType>vsDataRncFunction</xn:vsDataType>
                                <xn:vsDataFormatVersion>EricssonSpecificAttributes</xn:vsDataFormatVersion>
                                <es:vsDataRncFunction>
                                    <es:amrNbMmMrUlTfcRepeat>OFF</es:amrNbMmMrUlTfcRepeat>
                                    <es:intraNodeIpResourceRef/>
                                    <es:mcAfterPsHoFromLteEnabled>OFF</es:mcAfterPsHoFromLteEnabled>
                                    <es:mncLength>2</es:mncLength>
                                    <es:nbapDscp>40</es:nbapDscp>
                                    <es:mcc>422</es:mcc>
                                    <es:eulFachEnabled>TRUE</es:eulFachEnabled>
                                    <es:mocnExternalNriMatching>FALSE</es:mocnExternalNriMatching>
                                    <es:evolvedHsUePrioLevel>MIMO_64QAM</es:evolvedHsUePrioLevel>
                                    <es:evolvedHsUePrioLevel>NON_HS</es:evolvedHsUePrioLevel>
                                    <es:ecSbhoTimer>6</es:ecSbhoTimer>
                                    <es:iuSccpConRateMeasPeriod>120</es:iuSccpConRateMeasPeriod>
                                    <es:networkResourceIdentifierLengthPs>5</es:networkResourceIdentifierLengthPs>
                                    <es:rimOptimizationEnabled>ON</es:rimOptimizationEnabled>
                                    <es:hsCellChangeAllowed>TRUE</es:hsCellChangeAllowed>
                                    <es:maxAllowedGbrDlPsStream>256</es:maxAllowedGbrDlPsStream>
                                    <es:pcapPositioningMode>SAS_CENTRIC</es:pcapPositioningMode>
                                    <es:RncFunctionId>1</es:RncFunctionId>
                                    <es:cyclicAcb>
                                        <es:rotationGroupSize>5</es:rotationGroupSize>
                                        <es:acbEnabled>FALSE</es:acbEnabled>
                                    </es:cyclicAcb>
                                    <es:hsFachEnabled>TRUE</es:hsFachEnabled>
                                    <es:highPrioScanReserve>0</es:highPrioScanReserve>
                                    <es:offloadDedicPrioEutraTime>5</es:offloadDedicPrioEutraTime>
                                    <es:aliasPlmnIdentities>
                                        <es:mncLength>2</es:mncLength>
                                        <es:mnc>2</es:mnc>
                                        <es:mcc>422</es:mcc>
                                    </es:aliasPlmnIdentities>
                                    <es:ecLocationAttemptUmts>OFF</es:ecLocationAttemptUmts>
                                    <es:loadSharingRrcEnabled>TRUE</es:loadSharingRrcEnabled>
                                    <es:gpehDataLevel>ALL_DATA</es:gpehDataLevel>
                                    <es:cbsFirstMsgDelayMargin>0</es:cbsFirstMsgDelayMargin>
                                    <es:cyclicAcbRotationTime>10</es:cyclicAcbRotationTime>
                                    <es:nwInitCallReestTime>20</es:nwInitCallReestTime>
                                    <es:primaryCnOperatorRef>SubNetwork=ONRM_ROOT_MO,SubNetwork=ERNC02,MeContext=ERNC02,ManagedElement=1,vsDataRncFunction=1,vsDataCnOperator=1</es:primaryCnOperatorRef>
                                    <es:fastDormancyDchPchEnabled>FALSE</es:fastDormancyDchPchEnabled>
                                    <es:mocnDedicPrioEutraEnabled>FALSE</es:mocnDedicPrioEutraEnabled>
                                    <es:userLabel>ERNC02</es:userLabel>
                                    <es:offloadDedicPrioEutraEnabled>FALSE</es:offloadDedicPrioEutraEnabled>
                                    <es:initialIuAccessRateMax>0</es:initialIuAccessRateMax>
                                    <es:rimUtraSiTimeout>40</es:rimUtraSiTimeout>
                                    <es:ecCnSbhoRequestIgnore>FALSE</es:ecCnSbhoRequestIgnore>
                                    <es:ecCnPriorityLevel>7</es:ecCnPriorityLevel>
                                    <es:loadSharingDirRetryEnabled>TRUE</es:loadSharingDirRetryEnabled>
                                    <es:iuSccpConRateThresh>10000</es:iuSccpConRateThresh>
                                    <es:eulUsersAdmEulHsCcEnabled>FALSE</es:eulUsersAdmEulHsCcEnabled>
                                    <es:evolvedHsUePrioEnabled>FALSE</es:evolvedHsUePrioEnabled>
                                    <es:rncType>RNC_8200</es:rncType>
                                    <es:cyclicAcbPs>
                                        <es:rotationGroupSize>5</es:rotationGroupSize>
                                        <es:acbEnabled>FALSE</es:acbEnabled>
                                    </es:cyclicAcbPs>
                                    <es:fastDormancyMethod>RELEASE</es:fastDormancyMethod>
                                    <es:csPriorityRabSetupTime>100</es:csPriorityRabSetupTime>
                                    <es:robustRwrEutraEnabled>TRUE</es:robustRwrEutraEnabled>
                                    <es:gpehFileSize>90000</es:gpehFileSize>
                                    <es:spareC>0</es:spareC>
                                    <es:spareC>0</es:spareC>
                                    <es:fbrPreventAccessEnabled>TRUE</es:fbrPreventAccessEnabled>
                                    <es:rncId>601</es:rncId>
                                    <es:nbapAuditInterval>0</es:nbapAuditInterval>
                                    <es:ctchAdmCtrl>FALSE</es:ctchAdmCtrl>
                                    <es:hsToDchTrigger>
                                        <es:servHsChangeInterRnc>ON</es:servHsChangeInterRnc>
                                        <es:poorQualityDetected>ON</es:poorQualityDetected>
                                        <es:servHsChangeIntraRnc>ON</es:servHsChangeIntraRnc>
                                        <es:changeOfBestCellInterRnc>ON</es:changeOfBestCellInterRnc>
                                        <es:changeOfBestCellIntraRnc>ON</es:changeOfBestCellIntraRnc>
                                    </es:hsToDchTrigger>
                                    <es:spareB>0</es:spareB>
                                    <es:spareB>0</es:spareB>
                                    <es:hsOnlyBestCell>FALSE</es:hsOnlyBestCell>
                                    <es:spare>0</es:spare>
                                    <es:spare>0</es:spare>
                                    <es:spareA>0</es:spareA>
                                    <es:spareA>0</es:spareA>
                                    <es:mnc>2</es:mnc>
                                    <es:rimUtraSiRetries>5</es:rimUtraSiRetries>
                                    <es:uetrFileSize>275</es:uetrFileSize>
                                    <es:networkResourceIdentifierLengthCs>0</es:networkResourceIdentifierLengthCs>
                                    <es:cyclicAcbCs>
                                        <es:rotationGroupSize>5</es:rotationGroupSize>
                                        <es:acbEnabled>FALSE</es:acbEnabled>
                                    </es:cyclicAcbCs>
                                    <es:ctrFileSize>5000</es:ctrFileSize>
                                    <es:emergencyCallRedirect>OFF</es:emergencyCallRedirect>
                                    <es:evolvedHsUePrioLoadThresh>50</es:evolvedHsUePrioLoadThresh>
                                    <es:softCongestionAllModules>1</es:softCongestionAllModules>
                                    <es:garbledSpeechCorrectionEnabled>TRUE</es:garbledSpeechCorrectionEnabled>
                                    <es:mocnDedicatedCellsSupport>OFF</es:mocnDedicatedCellsSupport>
                                    <es:enhUeDrxEnabled>FALSE</es:enhUeDrxEnabled>
                                </es:vsDataRncFunction>
                            </xn:attributes>
                            <xn:VsDataContainer id="UQ01150U9F1A">
                                <xn:attributes>
                                    <xn:vsDataType>vsDataUtranCell</xn:vsDataType>
                                    <xn:vsDataFormatVersion>EricssonSpecificAttributes</xn:vsDataFormatVersion>
                                    <es:vsDataUtranCell>
                                        <es:sib1PlmnScopeValueTag>1</es:sib1PlmnScopeValueTag>
                                        <es:secondarySchPower>-35</es:secondarySchPower>
                                        <es:primaryCpichPower>330</es:primaryCpichPower>
                                        <es:servDiffRrcAdmHighPrioProfile>SPEECH_ONLY</es:servDiffRrcAdmHighPrioProfile>
                                    </es:vsDataUtranCell>
                                </xn:attributes>
                                <xn:VsDataContainer id="UQ01150U21F2A">
                                    <xn:attributes>
                                        <xn:vsDataType>vsDataCoverageRelation</xn:vsDataType>
                                        <xn:vsDataFormatVersion>EricssonSpecificAttributes</xn:vsDataFormatVersion>
                                        <es:vsDataCoverageRelation>
                                            <es:CoverageRelationId>UQ01150U21F2A</es:CoverageRelationId>
                                            <es:hsIflsDownswitch>OFF</es:hsIflsDownswitch>
                                            <es:hsPathlossThreshold>80</es:hsPathlossThreshold>
                                        </es:vsDataCoverageRelation>
                                    </xn:attributes>
                                </xn:VsDataContainer>
                                <xn:VsDataContainer id="1700">
                                    <xn:attributes>
                                        <xn:vsDataType>vsDataEutranFreqRelation</xn:vsDataType>
                                        <xn:vsDataFormatVersion>EricssonSpecificAttributes</xn:vsDataFormatVersion>
                                        <es:vsDataEutranFreqRelation>
                                            <es:barredCnOperatorRef/>
                                            <es:userLabel/>
                                            <es:thresh2dRwr>-25</es:thresh2dRwr>
                                            <es:threshHigh2>10</es:threshHigh2>
                                        </es:vsDataEutranFreqRelation>
                                    </xn:attributes>
                                </xn:VsDataContainer>
                                    <xn:attributes>
                                        <xn:vsDataType>vsDataGsmRelation</xn:vsDataType>
                                        <xn:vsDataFormatVersion>EricssonSpecificAttributes</xn:vsDataFormatVersion>
                                        <es:vsDataGsmRelation>
                                            <es:mobilityRelationType>HO_AND_CELL_RESEL</es:mobilityRelationType>
                                            <es:externalGsmCellRef>SubNetwork=ONRM_ROOT_MO,SubNetwork=ERNC02,MeContext=ERNC02,ManagedElement=1,vsDataRncFunction=1,vsDataExternalGsmNetwork=422_2,vsDataExternalGsmCell=35731</es:externalGsmCellRef>
                                            <es:qOffset1sn>10</es:qOffset1sn>
                                            <es:selectionPriority>13</es:selectionPriority>
                                            <es:GsmRelationId>35731</es:GsmRelationId>
                                        </es:vsDataGsmRelation>
                                    </xn:attributes>
                                </xn:VsDataContainer>
                            </xn:VsDataContainer>
                        </xn:VsDataContainer>
                    </xn:ManagedElement>
                </xn:MeContext>
            </xn:SubNetwork>
        </xn:SubNetwork>
    </configData>
    <configData dnPrefix="Undefined">
        <xn:VsDataContainer id="ERNC01">
            <xn:attributes>
                <xn:vsDataType>vsDataNetworkElement</xn:vsDataType>
                <xn:vsDataFormatVersion>EricssonSpecificAttributes</xn:vsDataFormatVersion>
            </xn:attributes>
            <xn:VsDataContainer id="RNC">
                <xn:attributes>
                    <xn:vsDataType>vsDataNetworkFunction</xn:vsDataType>
                    <xn:vsDataFormatVersion>EricssonSpecificAttributes</xn:vsDataFormatVersion>
                    <es:vsDataNetworkFunction>
                        <es:NetworkFunctionId>RNC</es:NetworkFunctionId>
                        <es:functionType>RNC</es:functionType>
                    </es:vsDataNetworkFunction>
                </xn:attributes>
            </xn:VsDataContainer>
        </xn:VsDataContainer>
    </configData>
    <fileFooter dateTime="2023-05-07T14:24:05.076+04:00"/>
</bulkCmConfigDataFile>
```

Further simplified xml for easy view:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<bulkCmConfigDataFile xmlns:es="EricssonSpecificAttributes.xsd" xmlns:un="utranNrm.xsd" xmlns:xn="genericNrm.xsd" xmlns:gn="geranNrm.xsd" xmlns="configData.xsd">
    <fileHeader fileFormatVersion="32.615 V4.5" vendorName="Ericsson"/>
    <configData dnPrefix="Undefined">
        <xn:SubNetwork id="ONRM_ROOT_MO">
            <xn:SubNetwork id="ERNC01">
                <xn:MeContext id="ERNC01">
                    <xn:VsDataContainer id="ERNC01">
                        <xn:vsDataType>vsDataMeContext</xn:vsDataType>
                    </xn:VsDataContainer>
                    <xn:ManagedElement id="1">
                        <xn:attributes>
                            <xn:userLabel>ERNC01</xn:userLabel>
                        </xn:attributes>
                        <xn:VsDataContainer id="1">
                            <xn:attributes>
                                <xn:vsDataType>vsDataMeContext</xn:vsDataType>
                            </xn:attributes>
                        </xn:VsDataContainer>
                        <xn:VsDataContainer id="1">
                            <xn:attributes>
                                <xn:vsDataType>vsDataMeContext</xn:vsDataType>
                            </xn:attributes>
                            <xn:VsDataContainer id="UX01170U9F1C">
                                <xn:attributes>
                                    <xn:vsDataType>vsDataUtranCell</xn:vsDataType>
                                </xn:attributes>
                                <xn:VsDataContainer id="41173">
                                    <xn:attributes>
                                        <xn:vsDataType>vsDataUtranCell</xn:vsDataType>
                                    </xn:attributes>
                                </xn:VsDataContainer>
                                <xn:VsDataContainer id="UX01170U9F1A">
                                    <xn:attributes>
                                        <xn:vsDataType>vsDataUtranCell</xn:vsDataType>
                                    </xn:attributes>
                                </xn:VsDataContainer>
                            </xn:VsDataContainer>
                            <xn:VsDataContainer id="UX01170U9F1B">
                                <xn:attributes>
                                    <xn:vsDataType>vsDataUtranCell</xn:vsDataType>
                                </xn:attributes>
                                <xn:VsDataContainer id="41173">
                                    <xn:attributes>
                                        <xn:vsDataType>vsDataUtranCell</xn:vsDataType>
                                    </xn:attributes>
                                </xn:VsDataContainer>
                                <xn:VsDataContainer id="UX01170U9F1A">
                                    <xn:attributes>
                                        <xn:vsDataType>vsDataUtranCell</xn:vsDataType>
                                    </xn:attributes>
                                </xn:VsDataContainer>
                            </xn:VsDataContainer>
                        </xn:VsDataContainer>
                    </xn:ManagedElement>
                </xn:MeContext>
            </xn:SubNetwork>
            <xn:SubNetwork id="ERNC02">
                <xn:MeContext id="ERNC02">
                    <xn:VsDataContainer id="ERNC02">
                        <xn:attributes>
                            <xn:vsDataType>vsDataMeContext</xn:vsDataType>
                        </xn:attributes>
                    </xn:VsDataContainer>
                    <xn:ManagedElement id="1">
                        <xn:attributes>
                            <xn:userLabel>ERNC02</xn:userLabel>
                        </xn:attributes>
                        <xn:VsDataContainer id="1">
                            <xn:attributes>
                                <xn:vsDataType>vsDataManagedElement</xn:vsDataType>
                            </xn:attributes>
                        </xn:VsDataContainer>
                        <xn:VsDataContainer id="1">
                            <xn:attributes>
                                <xn:vsDataType>vsDataRncFunction</xn:vsDataType>
                            </xn:attributes>
                            <xn:VsDataContainer id="UQ01150U9F1A">
                                <xn:attributes>
                                    <xn:vsDataType>vsDataUtranCell</xn:vsDataType>
                                </xn:attributes>
                                <xn:VsDataContainer id="UQ01150U21F2A">
                                    <xn:attributes>
                                        <xn:vsDataType>vsDataCoverageRelation</xn:vsDataType>
                                    </xn:attributes>
                                </xn:VsDataContainer>
                            </xn:VsDataContainer>
                        </xn:VsDataContainer>
                    </xn:ManagedElement>
                </xn:MeContext>
            </xn:SubNetwork>
        </xn:SubNetwork>
    </configData>
    <fileFooter dateTime="2023-05-07T14:24:05.076+04:00"/>
</bulkCmConfigDataFile>
```

Here is screenshot view from 3rd party software - XMLspy
[Grid View of xml using XMLSpy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6inuf.png)

I tried different ways to get output for this element '<xn:VsDataContainer id="UQ01130U21F2A">' using xpath, as the data i am interested lies here. I am trying to find series of attributes(`UQ01130U21F2A`, `UQ01130U21F2B` etc) and child elements from this path `./configData/xn:SubNetwork/xn:SubNetwork/xn:MeContext/xn:ManagedElement/xn:VsDataContainer[@id="1"]/xn:VsDataContainer`. Code below.

- Tried entering paths from the 3rd party software. Xpath from XMLSpy `/bulkCmConfigDataFile[1]/configData[1]/xn:SubNetwork[1]/xn:SubNetwork[1]/xn:MeContext[1]/xn:ManagedElement[1]/xn:VsDataContainer[2]/xn:VsDataContainer[2]/@id`. No Output, instead got error
- I tried this path `./configData/xn:SubNetwork/xn:SubNetwork/xn:MeContext/xn:VsDataContainer[@id="UX01170U9F1C"]` and got no output
- I tried this path too and still no output. `'xn:SubNetwork[@id="ERNC01"]/xn:MeContext[@id="ERNC01"]/xn:ManagedElement[@id="1"]/xn:VsDataContainer[@id="1"]//xn:VsDataContainer'`

Here is code i tried to just print out the elements under '<xn:VsDataContainer id="UQ01130U21F2A">' with library "xml.etree.ElementTree":

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

xpath_expression = './configData/xn:SubNetwork/xn:SubNetwork/xn:MeContext/xn:VsDataContainer[@id="UX01170U9F1C"]'

xml_file = 'data\dump_ericsson\other\\rnc_mod4.xml'
tree = ET.parse(xml_file)
root = tree.getroot()

# the namespace prefix and URI
namespace = {
    "xn": "genericNrm.xsd",
    "es": "EricssonSpecificAttributes.xsd",
    "un": "utranNrm.xsd",
    "gn": "geranNrm.xsd",
    "": "configData.xsd"
}

# XPath expression
elements = root.findall(xpath_expression, namespace)

# Print each element
for element in elements:
    print(element.text)
    print(ET.tostring(element).decode())
```

i got no output. What am i doing wrong with the path?

Comment: Could you update your question so that your XML documents are valid XML (so that we can use them to test our your code)? That means including all the closing tags up to the final `</bulkCmConfigDataFile>` element so that they will load into an XML parser without errors.

Comment: Make sure you have minimal but complete and consistent sample data to allow others to reproduce the problem. If the text mentions certain attribute values or the Python code has XPath looking for certain attribute values then the sample XML should include elements with those attribute values.

Comment: @larsks & MartinHonnen, 
I updated both detailed and simplified xml portions. Thank you for the advice. let me know i should make any other changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to debug this sort of problem is to first reduce your xpath expression. Instead of `./configData/xn:SubNetwork/xn:SubNetwork/xn:MeContext/xn:VsDataContainer[@id="UX01170U9F1C"]`, start with `./configData`. Does that work?

```
>>> root.findall('./configData')
[]
```

It does not! So that's where we should start debugging.

Taking a closer look at your input data, the problem is that your document doesn't have a bare `configData` element. Because there is a default XML namespace in your document...

```xml
<bulkCmConfigDataFile ... xmlns="configData.xsd">
```

...that means the `configData` element only exists within the `configData.xsd` namespace. We need to add a non-null prefix for that to your namespace mapping, and then use that in the xpath expression. Assuming we have this namespace dictionary:

```
namespace = {
    "xn": "genericNrm.xsd",
    "es": "EricssonSpecificAttributes.xsd",
    "un": "utranNrm.xsd",
    "gn": "geranNrm.xsd",
    "cd": "configData.xsd"
}
```

This expression works:

```
>>> root.findall('./cd:configData', namespace)
[<Element '{configData.xsd}configData' at 0x7f66ae291ad0>]
```

Which means this works:

```
>>> root.findall('./cd:configData/xn:SubNetwork/xn:SubNetwork/xn:MeContext/xn:VsDataContainer', namespace)
[<Element '{genericNrm.xsd}VsDataContainer' at 0x7fb757691d00>, <Element '{genericNrm.xsd}VsDataContainer' at 0x7fb7576930b0>]
```

But your original xpath expression still fails:

```
>>> root.findall('./cd:configData/xn:SubNetwork/xn:SubNetwork/xn:MeContext/xn:VsDataContainer[@id="UX01170U9F1C"]', namespace)
[]
```

That's because the `xn:VsDataContainer` element with the given `id` attribute is contained by another `xn:VsDataContainer` element, which is itself contained by a `xn:ManagedElement` element. So you could write this:

```
>>> root.findall('./cd:configData/xn:SubNetwork/xn:SubNetwork/xn:MeContext/xn:ManagedElement/xn:VsDataContainer/xn:VsDataContainer[@id="UX01170U9F1C"]', namespace)
[<Element '{genericNrm.xsd}VsDataContainer' at 0x7fb757692250>]
```

Or you could use a `//` expression to match an arbitrary number of levels:

```
>>> root.findall('./cd:configData/xn:SubNetwork/xn:SubNetwork/xn:MeContext//xn:VsDataContainer[@id="UX01170U9F1C"]', namespace)
[<Element '{genericNrm.xsd}VsDataContainer' at 0x7fb757692250>]
```

Comment: thanks for detail steps and explanation, now I have better understand in using paths. I will be using combination of this steps and hermann12's code.

Answer (score 1):

You have to search for the node`.attrib` or for a specific value node`.get('key')` not for node`.text`. This prints out all your id's or a specific one, but the referenced id="UQ01130U21F2A" is not in your example XML:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET


def complete_tag(nsmap, ns, tag):
    return '{' + nsmap[ns] + '}' + tag

nsmap = {}
for event, elem in ET.iterparse("rnc_mod4.xml", events=("start-ns", "start", "end")): #"end", "comment"
    if event == "start-ns":
        ns, url = elem
        nsmap[ns] = url
         
    if event == "start":
        if elem.tag == complete_tag(nsmap, "xn", "VsDataContainer"):
            if elem.get('id') == "UX01170U9F1C":
                print(elem.get('id'))
                
    if event == 'end':
        elem.clear()
```

Output:

```
UX01170U9F1C
UX01170U9F1C
UX01170U9F1C
```

**Alternative** with `findall()`, here I print the value only:

(But loading 5GB to RAM is not recommended)

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from pprint import pprint

print("#### N A M E S P A C E S ####")
ns = dict([elem for event, elem in ET.iterparse("rnc_mod4.xml", events=("start-ns",))])
pprint(ns)
print("#### N A M E S P A C E S ####")
   
tree = ET.parse("rnc_mod4.xml")
root = tree.getroot()
 
id_list = root.findall(".//{genericNrm.xsd}VsDataContainer[@id]", ns)
for id_ in id_list:
    print(id_.get('id'))
```

Comment: thank you for the answer. I like how you u can parse the namespace from the xml, i will be using that.

Comment: can't upvote for due to reputation